# Get specific value from a PHP submit button placed in loop

Tags: php, html

Here is my Html and PHP code, I've commented all the details, I want specific data depending on which button is clicked by the user, but the button is printed in a loop, whenever I try to access it gives the last updated data in submit button. because every time while loop executes, it is obvious to change values of **$row** variable, how can I manage to get appropriate values according to which submit button is clicked.
can it be done using an array?
any piece of code that can help?

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/header.php';
require_once '../includes/connection.php';

//i got data from table
$sql="select * from shoes";
$result = $con->query($sql);
?>

<html>
<main role="main">
<section class="sec-intro" role="section">
      <h1>Products</h1>
</section>

    
    
<section class="sec-boxes" role="section">


<!-- I placed a PHP loop here -->
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
?>

<article class="box">
<!-- Printing Data of Shoe --> 

    <img src="<?= $row['image'] ?>" width="250px" height="300px">
    <h1> <?= $row['shoe_name'] ?></h1>

    <?php
    //cutting the long strings into short becasue shoe description was long
            $des = $row['shoe_description'];
            if (strlen($des)>70)
            {
                  // truncate string
                    $stringCut = substr($des, 0, 90);
                    $endPoint = strrpos($stringCut, ' ');
                    $des = $endPoint? substr($stringCut, 0, $endPoint) : substr($stringCut, 0);
                    $des .= '... <a class= "link" href="search.php">Read More</a>';
            }
    ?>
    <p> <?= $des ?> </p>
    
    <!------------------------------------------
    ----------------------------------------
    ---------- PROBLEM IS HERE -------------------
    ------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------------->
    
    <input class="button" type="submit" name = "submit" value="Add to Cart" width= "150px"; />
    
    <!-- THIS ADD TO CART BUTTON IS INSIDE LOOP
         AND I WANT SHOE_ID AND SHOE_NAME OF THAT
         SPECIFIC BUTTON OF SHOE SPECIFIC SHOE -->
</article>

<?php } ?>
<!-- PHP LOOP ENDED HERE -->

    
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $id = $_POST['shoe_id'];        //here i need the shoe id of that specific shoe.
    }
    
    ?>
      
</section>

<!-- THIS WILL REMAIN SAME THROUGHOUT THE WEBSITE -->

</main>

<?php
    require_once '../includes/footer.php';
?>



</html>
```

The image of the web page is attached for clarity:
[page display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRv6Z.jpg)

EDIT/UPDATE: The `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` isn't working as well ??

Comment: You don't seem to have a **form** element, which is likely why there is no **$_POST**. I'd suggest outputting a **form** with the relevant identifying data in each loop - that is, a **form** for each shoe.

Comment: I actually don't want to print the form of every shoe, I just want id of that shoe, and I'll redirect to the other page then with the session variable (that's my further process) I'm just not getting the exact value?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to another page how you have write in your comment then you have to use javascript. Change your submit button with:

```
 <input class="button" type="button" onclick="location='your-next-page.php?id=<?=$row['shoe_name']?>'" value="Add to Cart" width= "150px"; />
```

And then you can retrieve the id by $_GET['id'];
If you want to post the id, then the you have to use a javascript function with ajax or fetch to send the id via post method.

Comment: I worked as you said, but it is not taking any input or any click from me... maybe its because the loop is completed and button is no more accepting input, it is just printed. ???

Comment: ```` <input class="button" type="button" onclick = "location: 'add_cart.php ?id=<?=$row['shoe_id']?>' " value="Add to Cart" width= "150px"; /> ```` just printing a normal button NOTE: I've placed it inside loop where my previous button exists.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have do an mistake in my andwer. Now I've edited my answer. You need to change location:... with location =...  You have to remove the blank space from add_cart.php and ?id=... also.